# Getting more fields for a minimongo object using Meteor's publish-subscribe

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

The app I'm building has a Games collection. Each object in this collection has a ton of data associacted with it. So much that when listing the games for each user, I have to limit the fields I send to it. This is all common stuff and working fine. The problem comes when I want to get more of the fields for a specific game, say when I go to its page, I need more than just the description and name.

The publish for the list of games is below, followed by the publish I'm trying to use to update the document with all the fields.

```
Meteor.publish('games', function() {
    return Games.find({owner: this.userId}, {fields: {
        name: 1,
        description: 1
    }});
});

//Publish all the fields for the given game
Meteor.publish('game', function(gameId) {
    return Games.find({_id: gameId});
});
```

My understanding of the publish subscribe functionality in Meteor is that the second publish would update the Games minimongo collection, giving the new fields to the object in the collection.

However my understandig seems to be flawed, or there's something with my implementation that is wrong.

When I log the games collection `console.log(Games)` on the list page, where I subscribe to the 'games' publish. I get what I expected, a collection that contains all the games owned by the current user. All the documents only have the name and description as expected.

When I go to the game page, where I subscribe to 'game'. The collection changes unexpectedly. When I do the same log as above, I get a collection that only has the one object, but has all the fields. This isnt what I expected, but it works for what I need.

The problem comes after this. When I do the client side select (below) on the minimongo colleciton. I get an object that only has the description, and name.

```
game: () => {
    return Games.findOne({_id: $stateParams.gameId});
}
```

I'm doing a find on a colleciton that has an object with all the fields I want, but the object the select is returning only has the two fields I defined beforehand.

I'm lost as to how to get this to work, and the problems im having are throwing my understanding of the publish subscribe feature in Meteor out of the window.

I can add some screenshots of the collection objects in the browser console if needed

Any ideas or suggestions to try?

EDIT: Here are two gists with my angular compenets that shows the subscribe:

game: https://gist.github.com/Jiig/f9577469d868a3165221

games: https://gist.github.com/Jiig/70dce515581ce12beb6f

Comment: Are you using iron-router?

Comment: @MichelFloyd No, using ui-router with angular on the client.

Comment: It all comes to what you are subscribing to and which template is been rendered (assuming you are subscribing on `template.onCreated`). Can you share a sample of your templates showing the subscriptions?

Comment: @lucatros Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using meteor-angular. Ill edit my question with a couple of gists that have my angular components with the subscribes in them.

Comment: @lucatros added the gists

Comment: @LucasVandenbergh I placed a comment on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe the behavior seems normal to me: you're subscribing to a collection with all items, and on the other hand you subscribe to a subset, so the Meteor 'magic' works against you here.

There are a couple things you can do:

- subscribe to BOTH subscriptions on the page with only the one Game: this will prevent the full list to be cleared because you're not subscribed to it, and it will only update the one Game with all its fields.
- split the Collections into Info and Generic options: that's a lot more trouble for you I guess, but is an option.
- Do a Method call to get the info for the one game: a little hacky but should work.

I think you should just try the first option, and see how it performs for you. In any case you should make sure you stay subscribed to the full collection if it's a long list that takes time to load.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first suggestion and and the collection is now being updated with the fields for the specific object, while keeping all the others there. However, my client side findOne is still giving me an object that still only has the name and description fields.

Comment: if you see the update on the collection, the findOne should retriieve what is there. are you sure you're not filtering the other fields in your request? try the find() with the object id if findOne doesn't work.

Comment: Useing find worked, and is giving me the right object now, thanks for your help.